# Dlib frontal face detection is not working in IOS.?

Tags: c++, ios, dlib

I am implementing sample face detection code using dlib package for IOS. I generated static library for dlib package.

**What I did**

1. Generated DLIB Static library for IOS.

2.Wrote sample dlib frontal face detection code for IOS, and Linked with dlib static library.

3. Compiled successfully.

**What I want**

application is working but face is not detecting. I got every time face size is Zero from dlib frontal face detection code.

Am i did any wrong.?

Can you help me why dlib frontal face detection code is not detect face.?

Can you provide any sample dlib face detection code for IOS.?

Comment: Could you explain how you generated a DLIB Static library for IOS (cmake etc.)?

Comment: Thanks for your reply..I builded DLIB static lib for IOS using Cmakelist.txt file.

Comment: How, ***exactly*** - what is the Cmake command line you are using, e.g. `cmake -G "Xcode"` etc, (any external tools or toolchain files)? - This information would be VERY helpful.

Comment: I used DLIB Cmakelist.txt and toolchain for IOS.                                                            

pls follow instruction :



mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../../../toolchain/iOS.cmake -DIOS_PLATFORM=SIMULATOR
make
make install

and you download toolchain from 



https://github.com/cristeab/ios-cmake

Comment: Thanks but not working for me => `ld: building for OSX, but linking against dylib built for iOS, file '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.1.sdk/usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib' for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [libdlib.18.18.99.dylib] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/dlib-shared.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2`

Comment: Just try set platform as device like below :

-DIOS_PLATFORM=OS

Comment: Doesn't work for me, Xcode 7.1, IOS 9.1 on El Capitan 10.11.1 :-(

Comment: Can you send DLIB source .? .Here We can able to build DLIB for IOS by did some changes in Cmakelist.txt.

Comment: Hi @Big Rich . I have builded DLIB for IOS as static Library. When i am trying to execute sample DLIB face detection. When I am linking static library into iOS APP. it gives linking error. Did you execute sample DLIB face detection code.?

Comment: [Facelandmarking with objective c and dlib](https://github.com/shaileshh/Mirror) small demo project for face detection using objective C n dlib.

Answer (score 1):

If you encountered the above errors, it means that you didn't build the dlib with arm7 architecture properly. To do this, add these code below (write after project(dlib)) to the CMakeLists.txt of the dlib.

For me, I'd rather like not to use the static library for my iOS development. I've run the landmark detection in my iPhone successfully by just adding the dlib folder in the include path and dlib/all/source.cpp to the project. To make the detection faster, you may change the original face detection with the legacy hear-cascade (set the detection size at around 70 will give you more than 40 fps in iPhone6s).

Good luck.

---

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-arc -std=gnu++11 -stdlib=libc++ -isysroot ${CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT}")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-arc -isysroot ${CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT}")

IF (${SIMULATOR})
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -mios-simulator-version-min=6.0")
ENDIF()
```

Comment: Hi Prima Oda I've tried your solution:
I've imported the dlib as a reference folder ->  https://s21.postimg.org/8ywhezq7r/Screen+Shot+2016-04-11+at+12.33.36.png

Then I've added the source.cpp to the project folder
https://s21.postimg.org/lp0ps2y5z/Screen+Shot+2016-04-11+at+12.33.53.png

But I get this error:-> /Users/utente/Documents/dlib/dlib-18.18/dlib/gui_widgets/nativefont.h:27:10: 'X11/Xlib.h' file not found
https://s21.postimg.org/w1n0e5rp3/Screen+Shot+2016-04-11+at+12.34.14.png

Comment: Can you please publish a video sample, on how to do that? It's not working for my team :\